# Exclude a specific package from a ControllerAdvice annotated class

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it possible to exclude a certain package from ControllerAdvice?

Something like:

```
@ControllerAdvice(value="com.company.integration")
@ControllerAdvice(exclude="com.company.integration.xxx")
Public class IntegrationExceptionHandler {

}
```

Comment: As I know, you define the exception you want to handle in your ControllerAdvice and only those exceptions are handle.